# Bash: Program next execution of current script using 'at'

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I want to execute a script and make it schedule the next execution. A sample would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

TMP=/tmp/text.txt
SCRIPT=$(readlink -f $0)

date >>$TMP
at -f $SCRIPT now + 1 minutes >>$TMP 2>&1
echo -e "\n" >>$TMP
```

A sample execution would do as follows:

1. First execution OK. Schedules to next minute
2. Second execution writes OK but doesn't schedule

Resulting output would be:

```
tue mar  5 14:34:01 CET 2013
job 15 at 2013-03-05 14:35


tue mar  5 14:35:00 CET 2013
job 16 at 2013-03-05 14:36

[now at 2013-03-05 14:38]
```

`atq` outputs nothing and I don't see any /var/at/jobs (In fact, `ls /var/at*` outputs nothing. There is no message in any user in /var/mail/. I'm trying on a CentOS release 5.6 x86_64

Anyone has any hint as to what may be happening?

Comment: have you checked the output of this line-: SCRIPT=$(readlink -f $0) ?

Comment: Try running the script using its fully qualified heirarchic name, for example: `/home/fred/bin/myscript` it could be that second time around it is running from a different directory.

Answer (score 1):

suspectus, you have hit the point... `echo $SCRIPT` gives '/bin/bash'... I've manually written the full path and now it works